# SQL to HQL for 'group by' with a nested join

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, nhibernate, hql

**Is it possible to convert this SQL to HQL?** 
I have tried but I am having difficulty with the nested join syntax.

```
select 
    emp.FirstName,
    nestedEmp.Hours
from Employee emp
join 
    (select 
        e.Id,
        w.WorkTimeType,
        Hours = SUM(hours)
    from Employee e
    left join WorkTimeEntry w on e.Id  = w.EmployeeId
    group by e.Id, w.WorkTimeType) as nestedEmp
on emp.Id = nestedEmp.Id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-subqueries) says:

> Note that HQL subqueries can occur only in the select or where clauses

So, this is not possible to translate it directly to HQL. (Note: I checked for Hibernate, but it must be the same in NHibernate).

Answer (score 1):

Building on what @JBNizet wrote, try this approach instead (untested)

```
select 
    emp.FirstName,
    (select sum(hours)
     from WorkTimeEntry w
     where w.Employee = emp)
from Employee emp
```

Some things to note:

- You should map an `Employee` reference, not an `EmployeeId` scalar
- I didn't include your grouping clause because you are not doing anything with the `WorkTimeType`. Are you sure this is what you want? (you can re-add it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about HQL but it looks like your best bet (if its possible) is to insert this data to a [table variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx), [temporary table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) or [common table expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx).

You can then join to one of these three like you would a regular table.

Depending on your data requirements, one may be more suitable than the other. Typically people recommend only to use table variables for very small datasets (less than 100 rows) though, so bear that in mind.